# Most efficient way to exclude words from hashing

Tags: java, regex, hash, full-text-search

I am working on a small project that will essentially search for a user-given word in multiple text files. I plan on accomplishing this by hashing each file into a large hash table prior to the search, then hashing the user's choice of word and comparing it to the hashtable.

My issue is that I would like to exclude certain common words like "the" from my hashing. The two ways I have thought of to do this are as follows:

1. Create a regex which is essentially "\bword1\b|\bword2\b|" and so on and so forth, and then do a `String.split(regex,"")` to remove those words from the text before I start hashing
2. As I process each word, do a `String.matches(regex)` to check to see if that word falls into my regex of excluded words. If it does, simply skip to the next word.

I feel like these two solutions are very similar, and am wondering if there might be a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Instead of using regular expressions, just store all your words-to-ignore in a `HashSet` or some other O(1)-lookup data structure.  Then parse the files word by word and see if each is in the ignore `Set` before processing it further.  The `Set` operations will *probably* be faster than any regular expression you can cook up (but I have not run any experiments to know for sure).

Comment: what you do if you found word ? In other words what is your key and value for your hash table ( i assume word is key)

Comment: @Mani I was going to have the words be keys, and the values be lists of what files contained the words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest maintaining a `HashSet` of stopwords (that's the official term in the field of Information Retrieval). You just check `stopwords.contains(word)`.

Let me also suggest a technique used to quickly search for words in documents: the *inverted index*. Don't maintain a hashmap per file; maintain a single hashmap where keys are words and values are sets of document IDs containing the word.

Then, if you want to search for all documents containing two given words, you'll be able to serve that request by just fetching two sets and calculating their intersection.

Comment: instead of a hashmap of words/a set of documents- use a multimap of word/document

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum But that calls for a third-party library. Also, efficient intersections call for sets, whereas a typical multimap uses a list of values.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum This is a small learning project. Obviously, everyone would use Lucene otherwise.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Great suggestions! A question:

1. Will using the `HashSet` like you suggest simply be easier from a coding perspective, or will it have a faster runtime as well? If the latter, how does it manage to increase the speed of execution over the methods I had posted originally?

Also, I think I may have described my hashing poorly. I was going to create one large hashtable rather than individual small ones for each document, which seems similar to inverted indexing.

Comment: @user3035026 The speedup is obtained through the hashcode mechanism: instead of linearly searching through the stopword list, you calculate the hashcode of your word and directly jump to the stopword with the same hashcode in the set---or directly find out that no stopword has that hashcode. All this hashcode manipulation happens behind the scenes when you call `stopowrds.contains(word)`.